# How to write a Android test case that spans over 2 applications

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing

According to the Robotium doc we can not write test case spans two applications, it says "the test project is locked to the targetPackage. Going outside of that target package is not allowed by the Android platform. Therefore you will need 2 test projects, one for each application."

Currently what I want to do is like monkey tool. I want to randomly fire actions on the screen to exhaustively trigger application's function. During the traversing process, the program flow sometimes will go out of the application and then JUnit or Robotium lose control of the program. I want to know is there any way that I can direct the program flow back to the application? Or is there any way that I can take control of multiple applications at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One Easy thing to do with write a simple Application which access the Activity Manager and reads every 2 seconds what is active as an external service within your app or another application altogether.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html

Basically, check that the ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo() and check that the Activity Component it was started from is one which you are OK with. Then, so that it does not affect your normal user, `.isUserAMonkey()` return a boolean of true.

If the Activity is not what you want, write:

```
else
startService(new Intent(this, TheService.class));
```

or

```
else 
startActivity(new Intent(this, TheActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to test only on Android 4.1 and above, you can use the new UI Automator framework, which supports testing across multiple packages.

Some info:
https://plus.google.com/103712615773524578393/posts/dzqtF7BYyG4